# different behavior of keyword "this" between node.js and browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I've tried following code in ie, firefox and node.js

```
var x = 10;
var o = { x: 15 };
function f(){
     console.log(this.x);
}
f();
f.call(o);
```

the results in browsers are 10, 15, but the result in node.js is undefined, 15.

Please explain to me what is the different behavior of “this” keyword in browsers and node.js? I've read many pages but there wasn't any obvious answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe Node.js runs in strict mode, by default... (In strict mode, `this`, inside a function, never coerces to the global object.)

Comment: How are you loading this code into node.js?  You would see this behavior if whatever loaded the node.js code parsed it as a function body as via `new Function(javascriptSourceCode)()` because then `var x` would declare a variable local to a function instead of being a top level global.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, in that case you would get an exception dereferencing `null`, not `undefined` for `this.x`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel, i copied the code into a file test.js and ran that file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript files loaded in Nodejs are automatically wrapped in anonymous functions.

So in Node what you are really running is:

```
(function(/* There are args here, but they aren't important for this answer */){
  var x = 10;
  var o = { x: 15 };
  function f(){
    console.log(this.x);
  }
  f();
  f.call(o);
})();
```

The browser does not do this. The issue is that now in Node `x` is just a normal variable in the scope of the function, it is not part of the global scope. When you call `f()` this way, `this` within `f` is the global scope.

If directly put `x` on the global scope, it will work in both cases.

```
this.x = 10;
```

That will place `x` on the `window` global object in the browser, and the `global` global object in Node.

Generally, you do not load things globally in Node, instead you group your code into modules, as [described here](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html). There is info about the various global things you can access [here](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html). And if you are curious about the wrapper, you can see it [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L735).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please give me any nodejs documentation about that?

Comment: @CongNguyen Added a bit at the end.

Answer (score 2):

When calling a regular function as in `f()`, the behavior is different in strict mode vs. regular mode.  In regular mode, `this` will be the global object (e.g. `window`).  In strict mode, `this` will be `undefined`.

Other than that difference, the assignment of `this` in a function call is fully specified in the javascript standard so if you are seeing differences in different situations, then it is probably because of `strict` mode.  Add `strict` mode to both environments and you should see consistent behavior.

You can read the section "Securing Javascript" at this [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) for more info.

Comment: No, strict mode is not related to OPs issue. If `this` were `undefined` the function would throw, but it logs `undefined` (so `this` is the global object in both scenarios).