# Behavior of this in Node environment

Tags: node.js

```
function a() {
return this;
}

function b() {
return this;
}

console.log(a() === b()) //true on browser and node
```

But then...

```
function a() {
return "inside a";
}

function b() {
console.log(this.a()); //logs undefined on node, 'inside a' on browser
}
```

This is ran non-strict mode for both browser and node.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.  It has little to do with how a function is defined.

If you call a function as just a plain function like

`a()`

Then, the value of `this` inside of the function `a` will be either the global object or `undefined` if running in strict mode.

Here are the ways the `this` can be controlled:

### Plain Function call

`a()`

`this` will be either the global object or `undefined` if running in strict mode.

### Method Call

`obj.a()`

`this` will be set to the object, `obj` in this case.

### .apply() or .call()

```
obj.a.call(obj, arg1, arg2)
obj.a.apply(obj, array)
```

`this` will be set to the object passed as the first argument to `.call()` or `.apply()`

### .bind()

```
var m = obj.a.bind(obj)
m();
```

`this` will be set to the object passed as the first argument to `.bind()`

Comment: So 'this' on Node acts like 'this' using strict mode on the browser?

Comment: @HReece - As best I know, Node has it's own global object and will behave just like a browser except that the global object will be a different object.  nodejs can run in either strict mode or not in strict mode, just like the browser.

Comment: still doesn't explain the example:  running no-strict, the browser displays 'inside a', but Node display undefined

Comment: if 'this' were undefined, accessing on undefined would throw an error too

Comment: @HReece - Which example, in which environment in which mode? I don't understand which of the eight possible combinations you discuss you are asking about?  Which function call?  In which environment (browser or node)?  In strict mode or not?  Please be more specific about exactly which scenario you're asking about.

Comment: The second block of code on my initial answer, the example.  Running on Node, calling this.a() return undefined.  Non-strict mode.

Comment: @HReece - Are you sure?  I assume you are not in strict mode since you don't show code to put it strict mode.  I would think that `this.a()` causes an execution error because `a` doesn't exist on the `this` object.  Can you show the whole node module that you're executing?  You can just do `console.log(this)` in node if you want to see what `this` is before you try to execute `this.a()`.

Comment: @HReece - FYI, a lot of what you're asking about now is academic because you shouldn't be using an unknown `this` anyway.  You should assume `this` has no legit value unless you've used one of the specific calling conventions I describe for controlling it.  It's also possible that node sets `this` specifically when it loads and runs a node module.  I can't find any doc on that though.  But, I wouldn't rely on it or use it anyway.  No need.

Comment: This clears it up:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895651/different-behavior-of-keyword-this-between-node-js-and-browsers