# Retrieve members global to the module programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js

On the Browser, it would look something like

```
//retreive all enumerable of `this`
function globalMems() {
  var g = this;
  var ret = {};

  for (var prop in g) {
    ret[prop] = g[prop];
  }

  return ret;
}
```

On Node.js, `this` is not the same as used on the browser to refer to the global object (`window`).  How can I retrieve all members global to a certain module in Node.js?  I don't think there is any direct access to a variable that refers to it.  `global` is far beyond the specific module, `this` is not it when used to refer to it as in the browser, [different behavior of keyword "this" between node.js and browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895651/different-behavior-of-keyword-this-between-node-js-and-browsers), and `modul` is not it.

Comment: Modules can be written in any number of ways and export almost anything, can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

this will work for your function in Node.js.

```
globalMems.call(GLOBAL);
```

`GLOBAL` in Node.js at some extent substitutes `window` in browser.

However, my advise would be to read more about `this` in javascript in general. [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a good start. And not use global scope in Node.js for your developerment needs